# How to save/create rejected data file with vertica copy command using python 3.x

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, vertica

I am copying data from csv file to vertica table using following python code:

```
with open("D:/SampleCSVFile_2kb/SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv", "rb") as fs:
    my_file = fs.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
    cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter=',', header='false') ", my_file)
```

This is working fine, but i want to save rejected data too so i used this query instead to save rejected data.

```
COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter=',',     
header='false') exceptions 'except.csv' rejected data 'reject.csv';
```

This copying data in vertica table but does not create file for rejected data.
Is this possible to create csv file for rejected data from python? If yes then how this can be done.

Thanks for help in advance -:)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use reject tables assuming you are using Vertica 7.0+. This will create the reject files on each node and wrapper it with an external table view.

To use it, add `rejected data to table my_reject_table`.  After the load, you should be able to query that.

If you do a `NO COMMIT` (copy statement parameter) then the reject table will be temporary for that session.  Otherwise it is permanent. You can use this to help with your workflow that you have planned. If you want it to be temporary so you can query out all the rejects, having a temp might be better. If it is for long term storage and review of rejects, the permanent option might be better. If you want to make it permanent and still use `NO COMMIT` then just do a `COPY` one time with a commit and it will create it permanently.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Now i used this query to save rejected data in table. But i am unable to do NO COMMIT in python code. Rollback does not work for cursor.copy() command. Also how can i find rows saved/affected in actual table in cursor.copy() command. COPY cb.table_format2 FROM STDIN ENCLOSED BY '"' delimiter ',' SKIP 1 rejected data as table cb.table_format2_error1;

Comment: BTW, Thanks -:) Your answer is helpful to move to next level. I was stuck at this point.

Comment: `NO COMMIT` is a `COPY` statement parameter (but you will need to explicitly commit after you are done, the temp only lasts during the transaction). Also, `COPY` does return a result set with the number of rows loaded.  Try fetching from the cursor after you execute the copy.

Comment: NO COMMIT only works for data in actual table. After adding NO COMMIT in copy command if i explicitly commit connection then data goes to actual table otherwise discard. but error data always goes to error table in every case. How to make this error table data only available for current session only?

Comment: Also in case of copy command, cursor.rowcount return -1,it only return actual row count in case of cursor.execute().

Comment: If you are using NO COMMIT, then it will create a temp table (assuming a perm one has not already been created). Regarding the rowcount... it's an actual resultset, do a fetch. :-)

Comment: can i create csv file for rejected data from python as i am unable to identify which error data was entered in case we save it in table?

Comment: @WaqasAli  I didn't see your message before, sorry. There is an undocumented parameter to stream back the data as a result set. That said, I've never used it, and it could change at any time so probably not  good idea. You can query the reject table to get to that data, though.

Comment: I found path where file was being saved. I was expecting to save it on my local machine but it was saved on server. catalog_dir/CopyErrorLogs/tablename-filename-of-source-copy-from-rejections (ref: vertica docs). If we want to change path then we have to create location otherwise it 'll be saved on above directory.

Comment: Your above answer is working fine, but in first attempt when i was using NO COMMIT i have my error table already exist that's why error data was saving permanently and increasing my frustrating -:) Later i change table name (which does not exist) then it works as expected.

Comment: Ref: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/SavingLoadRejections.htm  Ref 2: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CreateLocation.htm